# Redirect/RewriteRule via Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect the below example URL to home page via Htaccess

> mydomain.com/?s=xxxxxxxxxxx-abcdef.com.com

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^/?s=([^/]+)abcdef.com.com$ / [R=301,L]
```

*but It's doesn't work.*

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryString isn't part of match in RewriteRule's pattern. You need to match against %{QUERY_STRING} variable using a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```

**?** at the end of the target is important as it discards the old querystrings.

Comment: Awesome!!! It's work. Thank you for your advise. It's very helpful and make me have a new knowledge. :)